# Ansible issuing warning about localhost

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am running the following `ansible` playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - vars/config_values.yaml

  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Set correct project in gcloud config
      shell: "gcloud config set project {{ google_project_name }}"
```

Which yields the following warning:

> [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
>
> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

Given that I am explicitly stating that it will be run against `host: localhost`, why is it complaining about no inventory being parsed and that the "provided host list is empty"?

How to remove these warnings? (without just suppressing them if possible)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

These are just warnings telling you that:

1. you did not provide any inventory file either with the `-i` option, in your `ansible.cfg` or by default in `/etc/ansible/hosts` (and hence none was parsed and it is empty)
2. your inventory is empty and hence only the [implicit localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html) is available (reminding you that it does not match the `all` group)

---

**additional notes**

`hosts: localhost` in your above playbook example is the target for your play. It could be an other host or a group (or a more complicated [pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html)). The targeted hosts must exist in the inventory to be managed. `localhost` always exists at least as the [implicit local machine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html).

You can read [Ansible introduction to inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) for more information

---

Although those two warning seem a bit redundant, they give different information (i.e. "no inventory at all" vs "inventory is simply empty"). As such they are governed by different config options

- The second warning can be silenced since ansible v2.6 with the [`LOCALHOST_WARNING` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#localhost-warning)
- The first warning can be silenced since ansible-core v2.14 with the [`INVENTORY_UNPARSED_WARNING` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#inventory-unparsed-warning)

---

For the records, the first feature as been added to Ansible by a [pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/37871/files) proposed by [@larsk](/users/147356/larsks), a stackoverflow user

---

So if you intend to run playbooks primarily targeted to localhost without giving any inventory to parse, you can silence both warnings as in the following one-liner (see links above for all options to set those vars)

```bash
ANSIBLE_LOCALHOST_WARNING=False \
ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_UNPARSED_WARNING=False \
ansible-playbook your_localhost_playbook.yml
```

If you want to make this permanent, you can add the following two lines to your `.bashrc` (or equivalent file for the shell you use):

```bash
# Silence absent and/or empty Ansible inventory warnings
export ANSIBLE_LOCALHOST_WARNING=False
export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_UNPARSED_WARNING=False
```

Note that, as explained in the above links, these features can be turned off for individual projects using an `ansible.cfg` file at project root:

```ini
[defaults]
localhost_warning=False

[inventory]
inventory_unparsed_warning=False
```

Comment: Thanks. Can the warning be suppressed?

Comment: It happens that @larsk that often comes arround here has proposed an accepted patch to suppress this warning. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/37871/files. You should be able to remove it [by configuration](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#localhost-warning). Thanks to make me discover that.

Comment: ...although actually the `localhost_warning` config option only suppresses the *second* of the two warnings listed in the question ("provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available..."). The other warning ("No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available") cannot be suppressed via a config option.

Comment: @larsks just updated my answer as since latest ansible-core 2.14, there's a `INVENTORY_UNPARSED_WARNING` setting to suppress this second warning.

Answer (score 2):

As a non-expert. in Ansible, I suppressed these messages by adding **localhost**  on the /etc/ansible/hosts. Then set **hosts: localhost** on the playbook file. You should be good and won't be seeing those warning messages.

**Hosts file**

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-38 ~]$ sudo head -20 /etc/ansible/hosts
# This is the default ansible 'hosts' file.
#
# It should live in /etc/ansible/hosts
#
#   - Comments begin with the '#' character
#   - Blank lines are ignored
#   - Groups of hosts are delimited by [header] elements
#   - You can enter hostnames or ip addresses

#   - A hostname/ip can be a member of multiple groups

# Ex 1: Ungrouped hosts, specify before any group headers.
localhost
## green.example.com
## blue.example.com
## 192.168.100.1
## 192.168.100.10

# Ex 2: A collection of hosts belonging to the 'webservers' group

## [webservers]
```

**Playbook file**

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-38  ~]$ cat msteams.yml
  - name: MSTeams    
    hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: false
    tasks:
    - name: MSTeams Sending
      uri:
        url: https://outlook.office.com/webhook/asdasda-asdasd-40sdfd-btryrty2-posadjfm,sdnfoersmdnrfoasf,mvmnmtrny40956839523842/IncomingWebhook/102938091283kdjoasdyo214/vnmlasdhfaosldnaehywe
        method: POST
        body: "{\"text\": \"**Header:** {{Header}}\n\n **Next Line Message1:** {{MESSAGE1}}\n\n **Next Line Message2:** '{{ MESSAGE2 }}'\", \"themeColor\": \"{{COLOR}}\"}"
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
```

**Command Result**

```
[ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-38 ~]$ ansible-playbook msteams.yml -e "Header=TEST" -e "MESSAGE1=Message_without_space" -e ' MESSAGE2="Message with space" ' -e "COLOR=##FF0000"

PLAY [MSTeams] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [MSTeams Sending] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]


PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: This indeed works but you should be aware of one possible caveat: declaring `localhost` in your inventory makes it explicit and as such it will now match the `all` default group if you ever use it in your playbook. This is usually not what you want. Moreover, if you really do this, I suggest you add `ansible_connection: local` in the inventory for that host to make sure the correct connection is used without having to specify it in your play/task.

Answer (score 1):

As of ansible 2.6 you can also run `ANSIBLE_LOCALHOST_WARNING=false ansible-playbook /path/to/your/playbook.yaml` or set "localhost_warning=false" in your ansible.cfg file

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#localhost-warning

Answer (score 1):

By adding the below `ansible.cfg`, it solved the issue for me.

```
localhost_warning = False
```

Comment: You can `export ANSIBLE_LOCALHOST_WARNING=False` in your `.bashrc` or equivalent and this will work for any project at any path. That also works for `export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY_UNPARSED_WARNING=False`