# Passing hostname to ansible playbook through extravars

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have to pass the host on which the Ansible command will be executed through extra vars.

I don't know in advance to which hosts the tasks will be applied to, and, therefore, my inventory file is currently missing the `hosts:` variable.

If I understood from the article "[How to pass extra variables to an Ansible playbook](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/extra-variables-ansible-playbook)" correctly, overwriting hosts is only possible by having already composed groups of hosts.

From the post [Ansible issuing warning about localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59938088/ansible-issuing-warning-about-localhost) I gathered that referencing hosts to be managed in an Ansible inventory is a must, however, I still have doubts about it since the usage of extra vars was not mentioned in the given question.

So my question is: What can i do in order to make this playbook work?

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ host }}"

  tasks:

    - name: KLIST COMMAND
      command: klist
      register: klist_result

    - name: TEST COMMAND
      ansible.builtin.shell: echo hi > /tmp/test_result.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *... referencing hosts to be managed in an Ansible inventory is a must*

Yes, that's the case. Regarding your question

> *What can I do in order to make this playbook work?* (annot. without a "valid" inventory file)

you could try with the following workaround.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - add_host:
      hostname: "{{ target_hosts }}"
      group: dynamic

- hosts: dynamic
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Show hostname
    shell:
      cmd: "hostname && who am i"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result
```

A call with

```bash
ansible-playbook hosts.yml --extra-vars="target_hosts=test.example.com"
```

resulting into execution on

```yaml
TASK [add_host] ***********
changed: [localhost]

PLAY [dynamic] ************

TASK [Show hostname] ******
changed: [test.example.com]
```

In any case it is recommended to check [how to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html).

**Further Documentation**

- [`add_host` module – Add a host (and alternatively a group) to the ansible-playbook in-memory inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html)