# Running playbook without specifying hosts

Tags: ansible

What I want my playbook to do is to first import the hosts from a text file that is filled by the user into my inventory hosts file and then run the rest of the playbook, but I get the following error. Is there a way to fix this problem?(When I run it twice, the first time it puts the hosts into my hosts file and then it runs the rest without any problem.)

> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no    
    - name: Run check_dbname.sh
      shell: ./add_host_to_inventory.sh
      ignore_errors: true


---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    user_hash_password: "{{ user_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"

  tasks:
    - include_vars: yamlvariable.yml

    - name: Generate the password for all machines at once
      set_fact:
        user_password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=20') }}"
      run_once: true
```

Comment: Right, he need to add the hosts dynamically like in [Passing hostname to ansible playbook through extravars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73373684/6771046) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not a good idea and you should consider using `add_host` or developing a dynamic inventory.

Meanwhile the problem with your above example is that Ansible loads the inventory at start and keeps it in memory until the end of the playbook. This is why it works on the second round because you already added your hosts there.

The solution is to force refreshing the inventory during the play with the [`meta` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html). This is more meant for dynamic inventories that would change because you made an interaction with an API (like creating a vm in a cloud provider). But it will also play with a static one.

Just add the following task right after the one changing the inventory in your first play

```yaml
- name: Refresh inventory after adding hosts
  ansible.builtin.meta: refresh_inventory
```

Note that there are no errors in your example, only a warning about an empty inventory and [implicit localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html). For more information on this and how to get rid off it if you wish, [this has already been answered previously](/q/59938088/59940796#59940796)