# Ansible Warning "No inventory was passed, only implicit localhost is available"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ansible

When attempting to extract an Ansible var value,  Ansbile returns a warning "No inventory was passed, only implicit localhost is available"

The command which produces this is -

`ansible localhost -m debug -a var=hostvars[inventory_hostname] --playbook-dir /ansible/ --extra-vars @vars/vars.yml | grep -zPo '(?<=\=>)((.|\n)*)' | jq -r '.[`].hostname'

This returns

```
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
https://example.com
```

The playbooks are configured to run as

```
hosts: localhost
connection: local
```

If an explict entry is created like so, the warning disappears

```
cat /etc/ansilble/hosts
localhost
```

Is there any alternative CLI approach which can be used to surpress this warning?

I tried the recommendation seen here - [Ansible issuing warning about localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59938088/ansible-issuing-warning-about-localhost), but without any joy.

The setup versions are Ansible v2.10.8, Python v3.11.6 are running on Ubuntu v22.

## Use ansible-playbook

Apart from updating the existing playbooks with something such as

```
- name: "List all known variables and facts"
  debug:
    var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

Which is not what I'm seeking, I wish output all vars for the current playbooks via the CLI, as per the original command, seen above.

Answer (score 1):

> output all vars for the current playbooks via the CLI

You cannot do that because there are [tons of ways](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id33) the variables could be included to a playbook and the [variables precedence depends](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#id42) on them.

What you can do:

- continue with the approach you're using currently, but you'll have to update your Ansible installation to 2.14+ as mentioned in the answer to the linked question (which makes sense as 2.10.x reached its EOL years ago);
- write a tiny playbook that just outputs the variables and import it to all the required playbooks using [`import_playbook`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html);
- if you switch to [inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html) instead of var files, you will be able to output all the variables for any host using [`ansible-inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-inventory.html) command and something like `ansible-inventory --inventory hosts.yaml --list --yaml --host yourhostname`.